# How would my world connect to Earth?

Tags: magic, alternate-worlds, worldbuilding-process, dragons, firstcontact

I'm building a world for the novel I'm writing (called Aroura) and it's a separate world from Earth. There are three tribes, the dragons, the elves, and the humans. My heroine, Galaxy, finds out she's half dragon and goes from earth to Aroura. I need some help figuring out how she'll get from Earth to Aroura, and how these two worlds could have interacted in the past, present, or future. (I can edit if I need to be more specific).
Edit #1: Portals are what I was thinking about it, but how would the portals have opened? How did she find it? How has it not opened until now? Stuff like that.

Comment: Magic portals seem an obvious solution, why would you have dismissed that possibility? We don't try to write your story for you however, so you would need to clarify what your specific worldbuilding issue is.

Comment: To be clear (because it isn't in the question) is Galaxy an Earth resident who wants to get back to the planet of her birth?  If this is the case, a means of travel must have already existed.

Comment: @jdunlop       Yes. Although she accidentally ended up in the world she was supposed to be. And yes there would have been a means of travel in the past, and it would probably be the same as in the present way. I'm just trying to figure out how the worlds make contact.

Comment: This seems completely open-ended with little guidance about what a right or wrong answer would look like. It needs to be a little more focused, or have details about how magic works, before we can give a proper response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are world hopping methods I can think of.

1. **Space ships.**  Someone shows up in one and gets her.  Maybe they are friendly - her people know she has come of age.  Maybe they are people who collect halfdragon women.  Maybe someone heard her play tambourine and want her in the band.  Maybe the people with the space ship are in picking up tacos and she jacks their ship.  In any case - a space ship.
2. **Space hopping tech**.  This was on Earth already.  Maybe it was buried in an ancient building like the Stargates.  Maybe someone had it and didn't know what it could do but Gal was messing with it because it went "woom woom" and she made it work by accident.  Or maybe it was handed down in the family and the owner knew what it could do.

Oh yes, of course: Gal has it because it is an amulet she has always had, a gift from her unknown mother, and it goes "woom woom".

3. **Astral projection.**  This one is trippier.  This is how John Carter went to Mars - some special out of the way cave and he laid down and woke up on Mars in a new body that was much like his own body.  His old body laid in the cave and got dusty.  Avatar is similar but you wake up in a giant blue body.  Dreamquest of Kadath is similar except dude is dreaming and thus explores the dream worlds.
4. **Magic.**   Sounds like people might have magic on Aroura.  One of them can summon her because she is needed, or because they saw her in a crystal ball and want to be friends, or by accident because they were trying to summon her hedgehog and she was holding it.  Or maybe Gal has magic and she is testing it out.
5. **Time travel.**  This answers the relationship between Aroura and Earth question - they are the same place but far apart in time.  Maybe Gal was sent forward or back in time depending on when Aroura is.  Maybe the tech used to send her brings her back after a given period so when time is up - she is back in Aroura.
6. **Aroura is not real.**   I was thinking of the movie Labyrinth.  That is a fine film in many ways.  If you pay attention to small things (which becomes possible on the 20th or 21st viewing) it becomes clear that the whole thing is imaginary.  The protagonist is unhappy with her circumstances and the world she visits is a way she can make sense of the state of her life in the real world.  So too Aroura, and this world can unfold in any way that makes sense.  Have you not watched Labyrinth??  You are in for a treat.  Probably once will be enough unless someone you watch it with really really likes it.
7. **Aroura is right here, now.**  This is like Faerie, or the world of Percy Jackson.  Gods and monsters are all around us, unseen or ignored by ordinary folks.  Gal does not need to go anywhere.  She needs to open her eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the green check Galaxy.  But you can just give an upvote and hang onto the check for a bit.  Sometimes when people see the check they don't put their own answers.    It is early yet; maybe an answer you like better will come along.