# Good ways to transport your characters from a modern world to a fantasy world?

Tags: magic, transportation

My character is being transported from our world to another world, and I want to do something original and unique. There are the classic options (magical artifact, secret door, portals, walk in the woods that just turns into a fantasy world, death and then waking up in a new world, etc.), but I was looking for something something unique. Maybe something to do with dreams? I have an idea where they meet someone from that world in dreams and then get transported after meeting that character and that's how everyone knows they're not a traitor lol. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this sounds like brainstorming for story ideas rather than a worldbuilding question. The site tends to frown upon this sort of question. Unfortunately (again) I don't think there is a good SE site for brainstorming story ideas.

Comment: Another problem is people like to close questions when there is no objective way to judge a best answer.

Comment: Hi Jena! First of all, I just want to welcome you to Worldbuilding! You've got a great *topic* about which questions can (and should!) be asked here, but this forum isn't like other worldbuilding forums. This kind of open ended, brainstorming, call for ideas sort of question is what we call "opinion based" in any Stack Exchange forum you visit. I voted to close your query for that reason. I think you can easily edit this question to be a better fit within Worldbuilding by starting with your *own idea*, the one where you say "I have an idea..." and build a question from there. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Since your interest, for this question, is dreams as a gateway, you could very easily turn your poorly written opinion seeking question into a stellar **reality check** query by introducing your idea, telling us a little about how your fantasy world works and basically asking if the bridge mechanism you've come up with between the worlds is a viable idea! We'll tell you aye or nay and help with reasons why! Please do edit your question!

Comment: Here is a similar question (that also got closed!) but that had some ideas you might use.  My favorite is the hedgehog one, because of the hedgehog.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197309/how-would-my-world-connect-to-earth

Comment: *"Something to do with dreams":* It is so unique that it even has [its dedicated Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_world_(plot_device)).

Answer (score 0):

**Stunning Word**

The common spell Stunning Word is known for taking someone out of a fight without doing permanent damage. The victim stands around staring into space for the duration of the spell.

What they don't tell you in Witch School is the way this spell works is by distracting the person's mind to live through a mundane life in the *real world* for subjectively decades.

That's right. Your whole mundane life was an illusion caused by a Witch who didn't want you stealing her potions. In reality you are an axe-wielding wise-cracking adventurer named Jeff with a thirst for potions beyond what is considered polite.

The Witch had hidden her potions and carried your limp body outside her hut. As the spell was about to end, she was ready to cast Forget Day -- as they thought her in Witch School -- but then she slipped and hit her head on a boulder and rolled into river.

Now the illusion has worn off and you remember your *past life*. Enjoy.

Comment: I understood this the second time thru.  It is the Cure song "Just Like Heaven".    Such a lonely song.  I hope she did not have anyone in her dreamt life that she will miss like that.  Although it would move the story along if she did.